# Depois de remover app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" desalinha do topo

Tags: android, android-layout

Quando eu removo o [app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429033/edittext-seterror-not-positioning-at-the-right-position) da minha tela resolve o problema da position do setError. Porem causa outro, após fazer isso ele não fica mais alinhado com o topo.

Aqui está o inicio onde eu removendo do meu content acontece o problema

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"> <!-- Removendo essa linha -->
....
```

Outra activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.CompletaCadastroActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_completa_cadastro" />
```

Se alguém puder ajudar. Grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução neste [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608564/coordinatorlayout-messing-up-seterror-popup-position), no caso era só adicionar um LinearLayout antes do AppBarLayout.